# What memory cards are compatible with my Canon Digital IXY 1000?

Tags: camera, memory-card

Would it be SDHC or SD?

I would get 1 Terabyte if I could afford it.

Please point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: there are no 1tb memory cards on the market, or even laptop hard drives. While the next generation sdxc cards support up to 2 tb, there are simply none. The biggest common ones i've seen are 16 gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This camera, like most cameras nowadays, is compatible with SDHC, SD and MMC cards. MMC & SD cards have a maximum size of 2Gb, while SDHC has a maximum capacity of 32Gb.

In order to get a card of 1Tb, you'd need to have a camera capable of using SDXC. This new format was announced at CES in 2009, with a maximum capacity of 2Tb, and the first cameras to use it are coming onto the market this spring, for example the Canon A3100 IS, or the A495.

However as far as I'm aware, the biggest SDXC card you can presently get is 64Gb, shipping by both SanDisk and Panasonic, costing $350 and $600 respectively.

Comment: So, this should work, right? 

http://www.amazon.com/SanDisk-32GB-SDHC-Memory-Class/dp/B002OWHZMI/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&s=electronics&qid=1271372632&sr=1-5

What does class 2 mean btw?

Comment: Yes, it's SDHC card, so it will work. Class 2 is the speed, so this will be a minimum of 2MB/sec. A Class 4 card would be 4MB/sec and so on.